# Strange MUI Grid behavior when using spacing

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, flexbox

I have the following code

```
<Box sx={{height:'100vh', background: '#f5f7fc', overflow:'auto'}}>
      <Grid container justifyContent={'center'} padding={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography align="center" fontSize={30}>Welcome! Please enter your childs information</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={10}>
          <Paper>
            <Grid container padding={2}>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField fullWidth label='First Name'/>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={6}>
                <TextField fullWidth label='Last Name'/>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
        
      </Grid>
  </Box>
```

which shows up like this, as I expect
[image: expectedresult]

Now, when I add spacing like

```
<Paper>
   <Grid container padding={2} spacing={2}>
```

all of a sudden the Paper sticks out above Grid, and the padding on the right no longer matches the padding on the left

[image: wrong]

My question is this: what?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this and it's working properly in my case. Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/headless-paper-r9szqy?file=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.js%3A18%2C22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Paper component can itself become Grid. Make it Grid container and add spacing to the inner Grid instead of Paper.

```
<Box sx={{ height: "100vh", background: "#f5f7fc", overflow: "auto" }}>
  <Grid container justifyContent={"center"} padding={2}>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Typography align="center" fontSize={30}>
        Welcome! Please enter your childs information
      </Typography>
    </Grid>
    <Paper component={Grid} container>
      <Grid container padding={2} spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <TextField fullWidth label="First Name" />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <TextField fullWidth label="Last Name" />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Paper>
  </Grid>
</Box>
```

**Updated answer:**

Issue: The Grid component has some negative margin limitations due to which spacing does not tend to work sometimes. Their proposed solution is to use `display: flex` on the parent component.

You can read about it here: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#limitations

```
<Grid item xs={10}>
  <Paper
    style={{
      display: "flex",
    }}
  >
    <Grid container padding={2} spacing={2}>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField fullWidth label="First Name" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <TextField fullWidth label="Last Name" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Paper>
</Grid>
```

Note: Now with the above solution. The width will reduce because you have `item xs={10}`. Making it `item xs={12}` will solve it as you wanted to have it span full.

Comment: This solved it! I don't really understand why though - do you have any insights as to why this happens?

Comment: I have added the explanation and also the recommended solution from mui.